# Golang Бесконечный цикл и загрузка ЦП

Tags: golang

Почему обычный цикл нагружает процессор?! (у меня нагрузку показывает на 50-60%) Например:

```
package main

func main() {
    for {

    }
}
```

А к примеру цикл на прослушивание порта НЕ нагружает процессор? (~1%) Например:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Во 2-ом примере тоже используется бесконечный цикл!

UPDATE:

Такой пример тоже не нагружает процессор, почему? ведь тут тоже используется бесконечный цикл!

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            continue
        }
        handleConn(conn)
    }
}

func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    for {
        _, err := io.WriteString(c, time.Now().Format("15:04:05\n"))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во втором случае нет бесконечного цикла. Функция `Listen...` использует низкоуровневое API операционной системы, которое реализовано достаточно хорошо, что бы не использовать бесконечый цикл. Высокоуровневый код вызывает что-то на подобии `WaitFor...`, и операционная система передает управление вызывающему коду только тогда, когда кто-то присоединится. Во время ожидания эта функция имеет почти нулевую нагрузку на процессор.

Бесконечный цикл всегда загружает одно ядро процессора. Если у вас такой цикл создает нагрузку 50%, значит у вас 2 ядра.

Comment: А WaitFor работает не циклом? Тогда как?

Comment: Добавил в описание еще пример...

Comment: Внутри операционной системы происходят события. Когда кто-то присоединяется к открытому TCP порту, операционная система это видит, и посылает сигнал прослушиваему коду. Сама операционная система не использует цикл здесь, она просто ждет сигнала от сетевого интерфейса. Во втором вашем примере тоже самое, Accept внутри ждет сигнала от ОС.

Comment: точно! добавил fmt.Print перед и после Accept! спасибо за разъяснение...

Comment: Zergatul, слушай вот от куда ты это узнал? На лекциях? От какойто книги? Я просто в гугл вбивал разные запросы на эту тему, так ничего и не смог найти... вот сюда и написал... Мож че почитать посоветуешь на эту тему, как все изнутри работает?!

Comment: На Pluralsight есть курсы Windows Internals 1/2/3. Там объясняют как это работает в Windows. Хотя курс не особо детальный, и каких-то подробностей реализации там нет.

Answer (score 3):

### В Linux:

> Почему обычный цикл нагружает процессор?!

Потому что его выполнение никогда не уходит из кода процесса, а работа в нём есть всегда.

ОС продолжает исправно выделять процессу время на выполнение, он всегда полностью съедает всё то время, что ему выделили, постоянно гоняя "курсор исполнения" вокруг одной команды (абстрактное "goto чуть назад", как бы оно реально ни выглядело), прерываясь только когда у ОС есть другие дела/процессы.

> А к примеру цикл на прослушивание порта НЕ нагружает процессор?

Потому что его выполнение **уходит в ядро ОС** по [системному вызову `listen`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/listen), и процесс фактически останавливается. Его код временно перестаёт выполняться. ОС запоминает, что "процесс просил его разбудить, когда на указанный сокет кто-то придёт".

До тех пор ОС не будет выделять процессу время на выполнение.

Так работает синхронный ввод-вывод в целом. Бывает ещё асинхронный, который не вызывает остановки процесса. Но процесс, его использующий, должен сам в удобные ему моменты спрашивать у ядра, "не пришёл ли кто". А в свободное от таких вопросов время может заниматься чем-то своим, грузить или не грузить процессор.

> Такой пример тоже не нагружает процессор, почему?

По той же причине, выполнение **уходит в ядро**, но на сей раз по [системному вызову `sleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) (возможно, он только оборачивает другой вызов, а не является им сам, но тем не менее), который инструктирует ОС возобновить выполнение только спустя какое-то время.

До тех пор ОС не будет выделять процессу время на выполнение.